# Evenly extruding edges outward of concave shape?

Tags: edges, extrude

I'm looking for a way to "evenly" extrude the edges around some somewhat arbitrary mesh outward.

I.e. The edges are extruded by the same length outward.

I've tried various things to no avail:

- extruding/scaling using the vertex normals
- extruding/scaling using individual origins
- push/pulling
- some combination between these, etc..

**Maybe pictures will help explain:**

With convex shapes, there is no problem (edges go out in a uniform fashion):
[image: convex shape example (works fine)]

On the other hand, with concave shapes the edges are extruded/scaled in a non-uniform way:
[image: concave shape example (doesn't work fine)]

I made a crude example of what I'm trying to accomplish with this (the overhanging grass geometry):
[image: 3]

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to tell from your description, but how are you extruding? Have you tried extruding by pressing E, but then leaving it in place with right click, and then scaling?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yeah I've been trying that approach and unfortunately couldn't find a nice way to scale it afterwards. I thought it might be possible to get it to scale from the individual origins, but that didn't work either unfortunately. I can imagine it will probably involve using the vertex normals, but haven't figured out a way that works yet. Tried a bunch of things and so far no luck. It seems like a simple enough problem though, and so hopefully the answer will be simple as well.